# Drawing for multivariable calculus.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does anyone have any step-by-step instructions for how they typically go about drawing 3d images, slices, and projections. I'm having a really hard time looking for good outlets/examples on how to sketch for my multivariable calculus class. Can anyone make suggestions?